Help for finding hollywood adult movie name
I need Hollywood adult movie name describe under..
In this movie one porn Star become neighbour of highschool boy, who live with his parents.
He watch her when she changing clothes, after this instant she come that Boy's home and industruction her self as new neighbor..
After this that porn star go for drive with that boy and in car boy remove his cloth, girl ask him for Remove cloth infornt of car, and that girl run car with taking his underwear, boy run little path  with covering pavate parts by big tyres and than sit in girl's car.
After this both become friend, boy go high school with his g.f. his two friends also shoched,. After few time his friend inform that, your g.f is porn star and show him video, both back up..
That 3 friends go in porn movies function and find that girls, there other two friend give introduce as porn film maker to one couple and there few funny things happen. All 3 friend run out from that function.
That, girls director have one parrot, I don't perfectly rember but that 3 friends group loot video tap, that time also funny things happen with parrot.
At ending of film, that boy and his friends makeing porn movies for educational purposes, that porn movie contractor meet that Boy's parents and show him what his boy doing, but actually his patent happy, because he working on girls guide to 21 century sex education..
At happy ending boy and girl become friend and working on this project..
Help me for identifying this Hollywood adult movie name..

Sounds like 'the girl next door' (2004) 
I was watching trailer for this on youtube earlier and i saw the film not long after it was released.




You might want to elaborate in which way this movie fits to the details given in the question in order to flesh out the answer a little more.
